# Drawing constraint-based optical layouts with angles and lengths

Tags: python, layout, constraints, angle

I've been working on an [optical layout program](https://github.com/SeanDS/optivis) for a little while, and it currently works by having the user specify the links between components (such as lasers, mirrors or beam splitters), the lengths of the links, and the angles of the components. That works quite well, until you form cyclic graphs, such as the following:

[Cyclic connection in Optivis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c50cy.png)

That shows a beam splitter connected back to itself via three mirrors. Essentially the loop is defined in pseudocode as:

```
link(beam splitter, mirror 1, length=50)
link(mirror 1, mirror 2, length=50)
link(mirror 2, mirror 3, length=50)
link(mirror 3, beam splitter, length=50)
```

(In reality each component can have multiple input/output nodes, so in this case the beam splitter is linked via front and back nodes)

The problem here is that, in having to specify all link lengths, you must somehow know exactly how long the last link must be in order to connect it back to the already-connected beam splitter. In my code I just ignore the user-defined link length if this happens, but that's not a very nice approach.

Instead, I thought of a better way to do it: the user can define a series of constraints based on link length and component angles. An optical setup can be drawn if it is sufficiently constrained by link length and component angle constraints, e.g.:

```
LengthConstraint(beam splitter, mirror 1, length=50)
LengthConstraint(mirror 1, mirror 2, length=50)
LengthConstraint(mirror 2, mirror 3, length=50)
AngleConstraint(mirror1, angle=45)
```

The above list of constraints, and the links, should form a unique solution for the layout.

I figure that there must already be some algorithm that solves exactly this kind of problem, but I can't seem to find one. I've looked at linear constraint solvers but I'm not sure if these work with angular constraints. I have also tried to write a solver that looks for optics that are constrained and tries to fit unconstrained linked optics around them, but this seems to fall down for more complicated constrained sets*. Can anyone point me towards an algorithm which might be suitable to solve this type of problem?

*For instance, imagine the above group of components, but uniquely defined only in terms of four internal 90 degree angular constraints and a single link length. This seems to be, for want of a better word, a "higher order" problem because to solver cannot just work out a single angle and link length but rather three or four simultaneously.